# how to define guild region for discord embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to automatically define guild region for *!serverinfo* embed?
If no, tell me, I have no idea.

```js
.addField('Region', ???)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using v12, the following code should assist you in what you need.

```
.addField("Region", message.guild.region)
```

Still having problems? Comment below and I can help you further!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)